# Restore Image from JSON-encoded binary data

Tags: c#, json, image, windows-phone-8, azure-mobile-services

I'm working on a Windows Phone application that receives it's data via the Windows Azure Mobile Service.

I'm trying to get Images from the database and display them in the application. Currently, I'm receiving the images via an embedded SQL statement in the Windows Azure Mobile Service API. An example can be found here [API Example](http://wptracker.azure-mobile.net/api/devicesgetpictures?phoneID=10045). All results are returned in a JSON string format.

How would I convert the value(s) of the `Image` field in the results into images that I could then display in my application.

I'm assuming that I would need to have an Image array and then convert each value into an image and display the images that way.

I'd appreciate any tips or advice. Thanks!

### Edit:

Here is the API that I use to get the results from the SQL database.

```
exports.get = function(request, response) {

if (request.query.phoneID && request.query.phoneName)
{
    response.send("ERROR #1: too many paramaters");
}
else
{
    var sql = "SELECT wptracker.Photos.* " +
              "FROM wptracker.PhonePhotos " +
              "INNER JOIN wptracker.Phones ON PhonePhotos.PhoneID = Phones.id " + 
              "INNER JOIN wptracker.Photos ON PhonePhotos.PhotoID = Photos.id ";

    var params = [];

    if (request.query.phoneName)
    {
        sql += 'WHERE wptracker.Phones.FullName = ?'
        params.push(request.query.phoneName);            
    }
    if (request.query.phoneID)
    {
        sql += 'WHERE wptracker.Phones.ID = ?'
        params.push(request.query.phoneID);            
    }        

    request.service.mssql.query(sql, params,
    {
        success: function (results)
        {
            response.json(statusCodes.OK, results);
        },
        error : function()
            {
                response.send("ERROR 2: query returned no results found.")
            }
    }
    );
}
```

}

Comment: The images are stored in a SQL database in a VARBINARY(MAX) column. The data is then returned in a JSON string format, which I'm assuming is still considered VARBINARY(MAX) column.

Comment: That what would you suggest I rename the question to?

Comment: Do you have any scripts in your read operation? If so, can you post it here?

Comment: Can you confirm that the images are stored in a `varbinary(max)` column? The [node-sqlserver driver](https://github.com/WindowsAzure/node-sqlserver), used by the `mssql` object in azure mobile services, retrieves data from `varbinary` columns as a `Buffer` object. Buffer objects aren't serialized as strings (they have a weird translation, see http://mobileservices.uservoice.com/forums/182281-feature-requests/suggestions/4670504-better-support-for-timestamp-columns). If your data is stored as string (nvarchar) how was it encoded?

Comment: The column that they are stored in in the database is varbinary(max). I uploaded the images into the database using dbForge Studio for SQL Server. Would it be easier to store links to the images in the database and download the images based on the links?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have queried your table and the value of that field is in a variable called `imageField`

```
string base64 = Convert.ToBase64String(imageField);
string htmlString="<img src=\"data:image/png;base64,"+base64+"\">";
```

but you will need to change `png` to whatever the actual format is